# File is corrupted after PHP File Upload

Tags: php, android, file-upload

All of the files uploaded through my android app to local-host is corrupted. The file size is lower than the original and I can't open the file because it is corrupted.

**Here is my android File Upload**

```
 public class FileHandler {
String response;
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream;
public String  uploadFile(String requestURL, final String selectedFilePath , HashMap<String, Object> postDataParams){

    int serverResponseCode = 0;

    HttpURLConnection connection;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";


    int bytesRead,bytesAvailable,bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File selectedFile = new File(selectedFilePath);

        try{
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
            URL url = new URL(requestURL);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);//Allow Inputs
            connection.setDoOutput(true);//Allow Outputs
            connection.setUseCaches(false);//Don't use a cached Copy
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            connection.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file",selectedFilePath);

            //creating new dataoutputstream
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

            //writing bytes to data outputstream
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);


            //returns no. of bytes present in fileInputStream
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            //selecting the buffer size as minimum of available bytes or 1 MB
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
            //setting the buffer as byte array of size of bufferSize
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            //reads bytes from FileInputStream(from 0th index of buffer to buffersize)
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);

            //loop repeats till bytesRead = -1, i.e., no bytes are left to read
            while (bytesRead > 0){
                //write the bytes read from inputstream
                dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable,maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer,0,bufferSize);
            }
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // Upload POST Data
            Iterator<String> keys = postDataParams.keySet().iterator();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                String key = keys.next();
                String value = postDataParams.get(key).toString();

                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + key + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain" + lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(value);
                dataOutputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            }
            dataOutputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);


            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Log.i(TAG, "Server Response is: " + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

            //response code of 200 indicates the server status OK
            if (serverResponseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                String line="";
                while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response =  line;
                }
                System.out.println(response);
                //  response = br.readLine();

            }
            else {
                response="Error" + serverResponseCode;
            }

            //closing the input and output streams
            fileInputStream.close();
            dataOutputStream.flush();
            dataOutputStream.close();



        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

            return response;
}
```

and my PHP Code:

```
<?php


require_once('dbconnect.php');


$appName = $_POST['appName'];
$acctID = $_POST['acctID'];

$file_path = "../app_file/";
$filename = basename($_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
$extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    $newFilePath = $file_path . $acctID . '_' . $appName . '_' . 'file.' . $extension;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $newFilePath)) {
        echo "10";
    } else{
        echo $newFilePath;
    }
?>
```

I cant find any solution on my problem. There is no error in my android app. File is uploaded with no problem.

Comment: `String fileName = parts[parts.length-1];`. Dont make it yourself so difficult. Use selectedFile.getName() instead.

Comment: Hello @greenapps! Sorry I forgot to delete that line of code, but I'm not using that one. I edited my code. My problem is the file size is lower than the selected file.

Comment: `The file size is lower than the original and I can't open the file because it is corrupted.`. Tell us both file sizes exactly. How do you know that the file is corrupted? Yes it is smaller. But are the bytes different from original? Please upload a .txt file. Then you can see what is missing as it will always open.

Comment: I checked the files inside my folder on htdocs. Example I have .rar file:
The original file size is (207,189 bytes) but after uploading it, the new file size is  (129,471 bytes). And when I open it, It will display an error saying the file is damaged/corrupted.

Comment: `dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0,bufferSize);` That should be `dataOutputStream.write(buffer,0, bytesRead);`.

Comment: Hello I tried to upload a text file, the content of my text file changed to:
--*****
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="acctID"
Content-Type: text/plain

69

^
That code is for my POST

Comment: Well then your other files will contain that too isnt it?

Comment: Add a totalBytesRead integer and sum bytesRead. Compare with file size.

Comment: You should add a stream.flush() at the end of writing.

Comment: `name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                    + selectedFilePath + "\"" + lineEnd);`. You should give here only the file name. Not a full path.

Comment: `twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens`. That boundary is different from firstone.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139856/discussion-between-paul-john-pulumbarit-and-greenapps).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I added

```
    private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```